# NaN displayed in input when changing format of value

Tags: angular, input, format, nan

I have my input in a mat form field :

```
<mat-form-field style="padding-right: 10px;">
   <input matInput type="text" [ngModel]="value | formatSize" (ngModelChange)="value=+$event"; 
   placeholder="value" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
</mat-form-field>
```

My pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'formatSize'})
export class FormatSize implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number) {
    return value.toLocaleString();
  }
}
```

My goal is to display a value which is formatted like this :

1000 -> 1 000

10000 -> 10 000

...

The problem with my code is that when i enter a value greater than 9999 it displays NaN in my input and my value is `ǹull` in my component.

***EDIT*** : reproduced code in stack : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7fxuqi?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `RegularExpression` to add space into number:

```js
const spaces = n => String(n)
  .replace(
    /(?!^)(?=(?:\d{3})+$)/g,
    ' '
  );

const numbers = [10, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000]

numbers.forEach(f => console.log(spaces(f)))
```

Code should look like this in your pipe:

```
@Pipe({name: 'formatSize'})
export class FormatSize implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: number) {
        return String(value).replace(
            /(?!^)(?=(?:\d{3})+$)/g,
            ' '
        );
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

You've got `NaN` because your value has spaces. So before assigning a value, we need to remove whitespades:

```
{{ myValue | formatSize }}<br>
<input type="text" [ngModel]="myValue | formatSize " 
  (ngModelChange)="removeWhitespace($event)"
  placeholder="value" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
```

TypeScript:

```
removeWhitespace(event) {    
    this.myValue = event.replace(/ /g,'');
}
```

Comment: Can't use `replace` on type number

Comment: still doesn't work, NaN displayed in the DOM if it's > 9999 @StepUp

Comment: @sowebull could you create a [stackbliz](https://www.stackblitz.com) example?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7fxuqi?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: note : if you copy this 89009789 and past it directly in the input, it will work.

Comment: So i think there is a problem when getting `+$event` when it is > than 9999

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't work like that. You have to use some sort of mask solution. It's a path of great pain and misery, the most popular solution being https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask

I used it a lot and while it has a lot of issues, it is serviceable.

Comment: it would be great to not use a library for that

Comment: You can't. To get what you want, you need caret position managing solution, not just type conversion and formatting.

Comment: What do you mean? It's a library for multiple frameworks. There's an angular directive packaged as well.